# Connect Raspberry Pi B+ to portable DVD player screen

Tags: screen

Recently I salvaged a broken portable DVD player. During the salvage I decided to remove the screen as I was going to try and get it to work with my Raspberry Pi.

My first attempt was simply to plug the ribbon cable coming from the screen into the ribbon input on my Pi, the problem was it didn’t fit. I researched the cable (26-pin FPC) and the screen ([datasheet](http://www.panelook.com/A070FW03%20V2_AUO_7.0_LCM_overview_248.html)).

The question is would it be possible to get the screen to work with the raspberry pi at home with a max budget of £100?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you the number of questions of this type I've seen. Unless you're particularly talented at electronics or you can find a specific tutorial for this, it's not worth your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most bare LCD screens either have an [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) or [LVDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling) interface. However, the details of the variations within these two groups will overwhelm the beginner. Usually an interface board is used to convert HDMI (the video port an a Raspberry Pi) to one or both of these formats for a particular LCD screen.

It may be best to simply buy a known working [HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) to TTL or LVDS converter that is known to work with a known working LCD screen (that is, buy a converter and LCD screen that are known to work together) rather then to try to find an interface that will work with the LCD screen you have.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look round the interwebs for a board.

Comment: Good luck.  This is may be difficult.  Not only will you have to figure out if the interface is TTL or LVDS you will then have to figure out the pin out of the connection.  After that, there is the "softer" bits to figure out.  Such as screen size and resolution.  Some of these setting may need to be set by the OEM of the interface board.  Start by identifying the LCD screen you have using what ever is printed on the part.  Finding the LCD screen on the web is the first step to finding someone who might sell an HDMI converter for that screen.